# Dell SC1425 fans running at full speed all the time and hooked up monitor shows nothing

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have a Dell SC1425 that runs fine for roughly 48 hours and then the fans start running at full speed all the time. I have hooked up a monitor but nothing is being displayed on it. I also have a blue light slowly flashing on the back and front of the server. The also also loses all network connectivity at this point aswell.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The blue light could just be the ident feature.  Pressing the button on the front next to the light should stop it flashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have a hardware issue that causes the machine to fail to load the BIOS.

The "blue flashing light" sounds like the server identification light. It's just there so you can easily identify the physical machine when you're on the OOB management board or RDP (or when you're in the front and want to be sure you have the right server from the back).

Advice: Call dell support.